# 1 Corinthians 5:4 - In what sense is Paul's spirit present in Corinth?

Tags: 1-corinthians, paul, spirit

> For though absent in body, I am present in spirit; and as if present,
> I have already pronounced judgment on the one who did such a thing.
> When you are assembled in the name of the Lord Jesus **and my spirit is
> present, with the power of our Lord Jesus,** you are to deliver this man
> to Satan for the destruction of the flesh, so that his spirit may be
> saved in the day of the Lord.
>
> 1 Corinthians 5:3‭-‬5 ESV

Paul specifies that the church is to take this action 'when his spirit is present'. What does he mean by this?

Comment: Surely the emphasis is on the _assembly_. When _all_ are gathered, then is Paul, in spirit, also gathered since he _would be_ were he present in that city at that time (there being but one body). I don't see a mystical aspect to this, merely a practicality.

Answer (score 2):

What *does* it mean when we read of the ‘spirit of’ this or that, or of a person like Jesus or Paul? Before we get to the passage, we might unpack the concept expressed here first.

There are many such expressions.

- spirit of grace Heb 10:29
- spirit of judgment and fire Is 4:4
- spirit of truth, of love, joy, peace, etc.
- spirit of glory and of God 1Pet 4:14
- where the spirit of the Lord is, there is freedom 2Cor 3:17

There is only *one* spirit- the spirit of God. 1Cor 12:13, and this enables the way of God to act in and through His children.

> I will know that you stand firm in the one Spirit, striving together as one for the faith of the gospel Phil 1:27

Of course there *are* other spirits, but these references are about those things or people contrary to God’s will.

> you were dead in your offenses and sins, 2in which you previously walked according to the course of this world, according to the prince of the power of the air, *of the spirit that is now working in the sons of disobedience*. Eph 2:2, 6:12

The spirit of Paul and of Jesus or anyone working for God’s purposes is a spirit of cooperation, of humility, of power for good and wisdom and of discernment - all the good and righteous ways God acts, are now distributed in the church.

> When you are assembled in the name of the Lord Jesus and my spirit is present, with the power of our Lord Jesus, you are to deliver this man to Satan 1Cor 5

The assembly of and cooperative hearts of the brethren instilled in them by God and His gift of holy spirit enabled that wisdom and discernment to act for the best in difficult circumstances.

Paul calls them, the church in Corinth, to act with his spirit of authority (as an Apostle) and the power of the Lord granted to the church generally.

> And the Father, as he had promised, gave him (Jesus) the holy spirit to pour out upon us, just as you see and hear today. Acts 2:33

They are to act boldly and decisively to free/protect the church from an obvious evil presence without concern for the brother who is only lost for the present time. Paul affirming that there is a time yet future that will provide for his salvation.

We need not think that Paul’s spirit was there or not there, or that some kind of timing was inferred. He speaks in a general sense of his presence with them via the spirit of God in him, whether he was physically present or not. He was always present in spirit just as Jesus was once he left to be with his Father.

> For though I am absent from you in body, I am present with you in spirit Col 2:5

Paul’s spirit is not to be distinguished from God’s spirit as they are the *same* spirit. God is present within the church by the various spirits of His appointed leaders, Lord, and qualities which God provides for the building of the body and its outward expression.

> being diligent to keep the unity of the spirit in the bond of peace Eph 4:3

Comment: (+1) Thanks! I think you've made a good exegesis of the passage at hand. It did come a little later than I'd expected, though. Some of the other theological baggage feels a bit extraneous, and introduces the risk of importing it into the text when we arrive at it. I was a little surprised at you taking that kind of approach, as it's one you tend to critique in others, and which I usually tend to agree with you on.

Comment: Huh?  "spirit of Grace" occurs in Heb 10:29 as another title for the Holy Spirit. "spirit of judgment" does not occur in the NT. "spirit of truth" occurs in John 14:16, 17, 15:26, 16:13, 15, 1 John 4:6, etc, as a title for the Holy Spirit.  I am mystified how you can assert such things.

Comment: @Dottard unfortunately when you approach scripture with an overbearing premise of a Holy Spirit person who has no name and no biblical mandate, granting unwarranted *titles* instead of attributes is sadly understandable.

Comment: @steveowen - that sword is double-edged and cuts both ways.

Comment: @Stevecanhelp that’s a good point about ‘importing’ I will keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

The Greek word πνεῦμα (pneuma) is used in a wide variety of ways (as in English) to denote a number of things - BDAG lists eight basic means for this noun and numerous sub-meanings.

However, one of its uses is: "*a part of the human personality ... spiritual state of mind, disposition*" (BDAG #3).  It is this sense that Paul employs this noun in 1 Cor 5:4.  Here are some further examples:

- 1 Cor 4:21 - Which do you prefer? Shall I come to you with a rod, or in love and with a gentle **spirit**?
- Gal 6:1 - Brothers, if anyone is caught in any transgression, you who are spiritual should restore him in a **spirit** of gentleness. Keep watch on yourself, lest you too be tempted.
- 2 Cor 2:13 - I still had no peace of mind (literally, "no rest in my **spirit**")
- Eph 4:23 - to be renewed in the **spirit** of your minds;
- 1 Peter 3:4 - but the hidden man of the heart, in the imperishable of the gentle and quiet **spirit**, which is of great worth before God.
- 1 Cor 16:18 - For they refreshed my **spirit** and yours. Therefore recognize such as these.

Thus, when Paul says that "his spirit" is present, he is simply asking that that act in accordance with the way Paul would act and decide such matters, if he were present with them.  That is, adopt the same attitude of mind as Paul's.